# "Function" & a "for" logic in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have an input parameter passed via a parameter dictionary as below -

```
paramDict = {  "Period":
                    {
                    "Description": "A Period",
                    "Value" : ['9']
                    },
               "AdditionalPeriods":
                        {
                        "Description": "An AdditionalPeriod",
                        "Value" : ['1']
                        }
            }
```

And, I have a dataframe "df_AssetCst" as below -

```
>>> df_AssetCst.dtypes
FLCO                object
FLN01               object
FLN02               object
FLN03               object
FLN04               object
FLN05               object
FLN06               object
FLN07               object
FLN08               object
FLN09               object
FLN10               object
FLN11               object
FLN12               object
FLN13               object
FLN14               object
```

Now based on the value passed to the parameter dictionary, I want to achieve the below "if-else" condition in python pandas -

```
def func(row):
    if pd.Series(paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0]) == '0':
        return '0'        
    elif pd.Series(paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0]) == '1':
        return df_AssetCst['FLN13']   
    elif pd.Series(paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0]) == '2':
        return (df_AssetCst['FLN13'].astype(int)
              + df_AssetCst['FLN14'].astype(int)) 
    else:
        return 'other'
```

In sql, the above case logic would be as below -

```
Case AdditionalPeriods = 0, Then NewColumn = 0
Case AdditionalPeriods = 1, Then NewColumn = FLN013
Case AdditionalPeriods = 2, Then NewColumn = FLN013 + FLN014
```

Now, I want to use the function to create a new column in the dataframe -

```
df_AssetCst['NewColumn'] = df_AssetCst.apply(func, axis=1)
```

But, this gives me the below error-

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')
```

After this, i want to achieve the below "For" logic -

```
if Period.value = '9'
then NewColumn2 =  FLN01+FLN02+FLN03+FLN04+FLN05+FLN06+FLN07+FLN08+FLN09
```

Can you please help me with some directions & the best way to achieve the same.Thanks

********** My Solution ***********

```
#1. Function logic :
def func(row):   
    if paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0] == '0':
        var = 0       
    elif paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0] == '1':
        var = int(row['FLN13'])   
    elif paramDict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0] == '2':
        var = int(row['FLN13']) + int(row['FLN14'])                                 
    else:
        var = -1

    return(var) 

#2. For logic
In_Period = paramDict['Period']['Value'][0]
colList = ['FLN{:0>2}'.format(X) for X in range(1, In_Period + 1)]
df_AssetCst['NewColumn1'] = df_AssetCst[colList].astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: `ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. ...` occurs when testing a condition between an `np.ndarray` and a scalar. Wrap the entire condition with `np.all()` or `np.any()`. Actually, `pd.Series` is probably misused in `func`. More info is needed, but I think `apply()` is used incorrectly, because the `row` argument, a `pd.Series`, is never used in `func()`. From [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): **"Objects passed to functions are Series objects having index either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the columns (axis=1)."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `func` function you wrote in your updated answer (i.e. your solution), you should be able to use the `DataFrame.apply` method with parameter `axis=1`. (I haven't tested it, but perhaps you could try to apply it and report the error message, if any)

However, inside this function you're referring to `param_dict` in the global scope, which, while it works, may lead to unintended consequences if you're not careful, and IMO, may lead to more headache later.

Here's another version of the `func` function. This one takes as parameters a row of type pd.Series, and a `param_dict` (the dictionary you provided in the question)

```
def func(row, param_dict):
   """
   Gets the key from the param_dict, and tries to return the element
   from _conversion_map.
   if the key doesn't exist in the conversion map, then returns -1
   """
   key = param_dict['AdditionalPeriods']['Value'][0] 
   _conversion_map = {
        '0': 0,
        '1': int(row.FLN13),
        '2': int(row.FLN13) + int(row.FLN14)
        }
    try:
        return _conversion_map[key]
    except KeyError:
        return -1
```

Then this should work:

```
df_AssetCst['NewColumn'] = df_AssetCst.apply(func, axis=1, param_dict=param_dict)
```

The key to this answer is that the `apply` method accepts arbitrary positional & keyword arguments and passes them to the function.